# How to Set Timeout for JAX-WS WebService Call

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-ws

I'm working on a WebService Client and I want to set a Timeout for my WebService Call. I have tried different approaches but still I'm not able to achieve this. I'm using JAX-WS for code generation from WSDL. I'm using JBoss-eap-5.1 as App Server and JDK1.6.0_27. I found these diff approaches for setting timeout but none of them is working for me.

```
URL mbr_service_url = new URL(null,GlobalVars.MemberService_WSDL, new URLStreamHandler() {

            @Override
            protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
                URL clone_url = new URL(url.toString());
                HttpURLConnection clone_urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) clone_url.openConnection();
                // TimeOut settings
                clone_urlconnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                clone_urlconnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                return (clone_urlconnection);
            }
        });
        MemberService service = new MemberService(mbr_service_url);
        MemberPortType soap = service.getMemberPort();
        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
        MemberEligibilityWithEnrollmentSourceRequest request = factory.createMemberEligibilityWithEnrollmentSourceRequest();

        request.setMemberId(GlobalVars.MemberId);
        request.setEligibilityDate(value);

        ((BindingProvider) soap).getRequestContext().put(com.sun.xml.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        ((BindingProvider) soap).getRequestContext().put(com.sun.xml.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        ((BindingProvider) soap).getRequestContext().put(com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        ((BindingProvider) soap).getRequestContext().put(com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        ((BindingProvider) soap).getRequestContext().put(com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        ((BindingProvider) soap).getRequestContext().put(com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        ((BindingProvider) soap).getRequestContext().put(com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        ((BindingProvider) soap).getRequestContext().put(com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
        System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "10000");
        System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout", "10000");

        MemberEligibilityWithEnrollmentSourceResponse response = soap.getMemberEligibilityWithEnrollmentSource(request);
        logger.log("Call to member service finished.");
```

---

For now what I have done is, I have called my webservice method from inside an executor. I know its not a good approach, but its working for me. Guys please help me to do it in a proper way.

```
logger.log("Parameters set for createorUpdateContact call.\nGoing in Executor Service.");
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    response = soap.getMemberEligibilityWithEnrollmentSource(request);
                } catch (MemberServiceException ex) {
                    logger.log("Exception in call to WebService", ex.fillInStackTrace());
                }
            }
        });
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(GlobalVars.WSCallTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            logger.log("Thread Interrupted!", ex);
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
```

Answer (score 24):

You could try these settings (they are paired to be used in pairs)

```
BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT
BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT
```

`BindingProviderProperties` should be from `com.sun.xml.internal.WS.client`

Or the strings [for JBoss](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/API_Documentation/files/javadoc/org/jboss/ws/core/StubExt.html#PROPERTY_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT):

```
javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout
javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout
```

All properties to be put on `getRequestContext()` in milliseconds.

```
(BindingProvider)wsPort).getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, yourTimeoutInMillisec);
```

For JBoss specifically, you might want to use the property `StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT` from `org.jboss.ws.core.StubExt`. See [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/101684?tstart=0) for details.

Comment: StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT worked for me, but  exception is thrown only after `3*timeoutMillisecond` 
For example: If `timeoutMillisecond=3000` than exception is thrown after 9000 millisecond, but `Timeout after: 3000ms` is written in log file

Comment: Thanks @mariami It worked for me. And exception is being thrown at proper time, not after    3*timeoutMillisecond . Although to make it to work I had to remove some jars from jboss lib related to jax otherwise it was giving    NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/spi/Provider21.

Comment: Is there any update for Jakarta specifications as many were changed from javax to jakarta?

Answer (score 8):

Like kolossus said you should use:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties
```

And String values are:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout
```

Although internal packages shouldn't be used, this is the only way if you work with default JDK6. So, in this case setting receive and connect timeout should be done with:

```
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT,requestTimeoutMs);

bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT,connectTimeoutMs);
```

**But beware, constant values are different if you are using other JAXWS reference implementation, i.e. JAXWS-RT 2.1.4 BindingProviderProperties:**

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties
```

you will have different String values for REQUEST_TIMEOUT and CONNECT_TIMEOUT:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout
com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout
```

Comment: Note that the given timeout is expected to be given as Integer!

Answer (score 6):

For me setting `javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout` and `javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout` solved the problem.

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", timeout);
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", timeout);
```

refer [link](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Develop_a_JAX-WS_Client_Application.html)

Answer (score 3):

Setting the following options works for me. I am using the Metro JAXWS implementation.

```
((BindingProvider)portType).getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
((BindingProvider) portType).getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 50000);
```

portType is the Web Service endpoint interface.

Values of the above fields from the com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties

```
public static final java.lang.String CONNECT_TIMEOUT = "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout";
public static final java.lang.String REQUEST_TIMEOUT = "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout";
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade jbossws-native library and use StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT

For upgrading jbossws-native,  follow this [link](http://www.jboss.org/jbossws/downloads).

*jbossws-native-3.4.0 is the latest supported version for Jboss 5.1.0GA. You can see [JBossWS - Supported Target Containers](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-SupportedTargetContainers)

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have a old installation runtime that have this environment:
Jdk-1.5, Jboss-4.2.3.GA and the WSClient was created by JAX-WS specification 2.0.

to activate Soap Request Timeout I use the follow code 
`((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(org.jboss.ws.core.StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT, String.valueOf(readTimeout));`

and the jar `jbossws-client.jar` copied in `jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\lib\`