# How to set JAX-WS client timeout?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-ws

I'm developing Jax-ws client on Jboss 5.1.0 GA.
I want to set web service client timeout.

I've tried **StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT**.

```
int timeoutMillisecond=3000;
bp.getRequestContext().put(StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT, timeoutMillisecond);
```

It works but exception is thrown only after **3*timeoutMillisecond** (after 9000 millisecond), but 3000ms is written in log file.

```
2012-12-24 15:42:40,053 DEBUG Sending request
2012-12-24 15:42:49,057 ERROR WebServiceException returned: 
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.jboss.ws.core.WSTimeoutException: Timeout after: 3000ms
```

---

I've rtied also many other ways

```
bp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", 100);
bp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", 100);
// from com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties
bp.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 100);
bp.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 100);
```

But nothing worked on Jboss 5.1

---

Could you tell me how to set client timeout correctly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Set Timeout for JAX-WS WebService Call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967069/how-to-set-timeout-for-jax-ws-webservice-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following steps and **fixed the problem**:

1. Upgraded **jbossws-native** library, [follow this link](http://www.jboss.org/jbossws/downloads). 
   jbossws-native-3.4.0 is the latest supported version for Jboss 5.1.0GA. You can see [JBossWS - Supported Target Containers](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-SupportedTargetContainers)
2. Used `StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT`

   ```
   int timeoutMillisecond=3000;
   bp.getRequestContext().put(StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT, timeoutMillisecond);
   ```

By the way, in this version `StubExt.PROPERTY_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` also works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [these](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/BindingProvider.html) settings for your service port.

```
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) YOUR_SERVICE_PORT;
Map<String, Object> context = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
context.put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 3*1000);
context.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT,3*1000);
```

Comment: BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT is the variable name for "com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout" and  BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT for "com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout" which the OP has already tried and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

you're complete missing the point check out code:

URL url = new URL("http://tst.com:9990/ws/hello?wsdl");

```
    //1st argument service URI, refer to wsdl document above
//2nd argument is service name, refer to wsdl document above
    QName qname = new QName("http://tstsoap/", "HelloWorldImplService");

    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

   HelloWorld hello = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class);
```

As you can see, you cannot get a port without creating a service first.
So the timeout always occurs at the service creation.
So setting a time for the port is pointless.......
Somebody needs to post something about service timeouts....not port timeouts....
Unless somebody can prove me wrong....