# Websphere SOAP timeout

Tags: websphere

From EJB transaction I am calling remote site using SOAP. Remote server is not responding. I got transaction time-out. But I want to get time-out from remote call.

How can I set time-out for SOAP request globally?
How can I set time-out for SOAP request for particular call?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure this using a Policy Set. See the link below for IBM's documentation on the topic.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Fae%2Frwbs_jaxwstimeouts.html

Answer (score 0):

To globally set timeout, you may use [HTTP transport custom properties for web services applications](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwbs_httptransportprop.html). The timeout you're looking for here is `timeout`. This is by default 300 seconds (which is more than global transaction timeout default value, which is 120 seconds, hence you receive a transaction time-out).

If you are using JAX-RPC, make sure you are at a patch level containing fix for [PM60752](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM60752) (6.1.0.45, 7.0.0.25, 8.0.0.5 and 8.5.0.1).

As indicated at Nick's answer, you have alternative methods to configure timeouts if you are using the newer JAX-WS stack.

When using JAX-RPC you may set timeout for a particular call endpoint as explained in article [Setting the timeout value for a JAX-RPC Web Service client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224016). For JAX-WS you may use bindings or go for one of the solutions at [How to Set Timeout for JAX-WS WebService Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967069/how-to-set-timeout-for-jax-ws-webservice-call).

One thing to keep in mind when configuring timeouts for web services is that web service transport depends on HTTP transport (assuming SOAP over HTTP), and in turn that depends on TCP transport, all of which are configurable for various timeouts. The relations between these layers and solutions to common problems are outlined at [Common Timeouts effecting Web Services, HTTP and SOAP clients](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233894) article.