# How to manage Java WS Timeout

Tags: java, web-services, timeout, settimeout, wsdl2java

I'm trying to manage a java timeout server response but I can't do it.

I call a WS but sometimes this WS is down and the program keeps waiting for a long time. If the server doesn't answer after 10 seconds, I want to continue with program execution throwing an exception.

Could it be posible? than you

Comment: Your WS library probably has a timeout feature. For example with Jersey you can use a client configuration like `new ClientConfig().property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5000);`.

Comment: I think yes but I haven't access to WS development. I'll send a message to WS team asking if it can be possible do that. Thank you :)

Comment: the setting is on the client, not the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Set Timeout for JAX-WS WebService Call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967069/how-to-set-timeout-for-jax-ws-webservice-call)